# Python3.8 cannot find command in the PATH env var (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, python-3.8, system-paths

When running a python script using **python38** it gives:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'riscv32-unknown-elf-objdump'

'riscv32-unknown-elf-objdump' is on my $PATH at shell command line, and also on sys.path printed by the python script itself.

If I switch to **python3**, then this error goes away.
The python line producing the error:

`result = subprocess.run(["riscv32-unknown-elf-objdump", "-S", "-M", "numeric", exe_file], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, encoding="ASCII")`

Any hints?
Edit: The version is defined in the script header, e.g.
`#!/usr/bin/env python38`

Comment: what is `python38`? I've never heard of a python executable named like that (only `python3.8`

Comment: @AnthonySottile yes it's python3.8, 
the shell command is called python38

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I found to solve this is to add `shell=True` in the call of **subprocess**:

`result = subprocess.run(["riscv32-unknown-elf-objdump", "-S", "-M", "numeric", exe_file], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, encoding="ASCII",shell=True)`

Still no idea why this is required for python3.8 and not earlier versions.